# How to add data in quickbooks pos print receipt?

Tags: c#-4.0, quickbooks

I want to edit the bridge of Quickbooks and the Printer. when consumer press Save and Print button. means add some text like thanks to shoping this items(list of items) in that receipt.

Any one help me for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using QuickBooks, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sachin, to add this line in every print receipt:

Go to File > Set up Interview.
A form will open with many tabs.The first tab "Receipt" display some info which you can set up based on your company. At the end there is a receipt message text area. Add your text to display in every receipt.

This is for POS 2013 Server version.